# useEffect is re-rendering async promise again and again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app

I am trying to log currentUser details to console to see if user is logged in or not. But it is logging again n again and make a loop of currentUser in console.
Here is the code

```
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const unSubscribeFromAuth = useRef(null);

   useEffect(() => {
    unSubscribeFromAuth.current = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
          setCurrentUser({
            id: snapShot.id,
            ...snapShot.data()
          })
          console.log(currentUser);
        })
      }
      else {
        setCurrentUser(userAuth);
      }
    })
    return () => { unSubscribeFromAuth.current() };
  }, [currentUser]);
```

and here is the function i am importing

```
export const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;
    const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);
    const snapShot = userRef.get();
    console.log(snapShot);

    if (!snapShot.exists) {
        const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
        const createdAt = new Date();

        try {
            await userRef.set({
                displayName,
                email,
                createdAt,
                ...additionalData
            })
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('error creating user', error.message);
        }
    }
    return userRef;
}
```

I tried to remove dependency but it says
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'currentUser'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating `currentUser` in the `useEffect` and the `useEffect` is triggered every time `currentUser` changes, you are seeing the infinite loop. You need to remove `currentUser` from the dependency array.

`useEffect has a missing dependency` is coming from `console.log`. If you remove it, it will go away.

Comment: I tried adding empty array in dependency but it does not log any data in console ( Promise <pending> null ) plus terminal is giving a warning

Comment: and if i dont add any dependency the same re-render problem occurs in console

Comment: You can `console.log` currentUser` out of the `useEffect`.